# MySQL Select Dates While Format Is 00/0000

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select dates from database while date format is 00/0000 which is 00 for month and 0000 for year.

I would like to select dates from database who is more than 09/2017

Comment: Have you tried a query yet and can you show us some data?  Are you storing your dates as text ?

Comment: Seriously consider storing dates as dates

Answer (score 1):

*Never* store your dates as text, always use a date column type for that.  If you must proceed as is, you can try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', date), '%d/%m/%Y') > '2017-09-01'
```

This query uses `STR_TO_DATE` to build a proper date from your string data, and then compare that date against the restriction you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATE_FORMAT() to extract month and year

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%m'),'/', DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y'))
```